# c++ - beep not working (linux)

Tags: c++, linux, beep

I'm trying to beep, but I simply can't. I've already tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << '\a' << flush;
    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried using this: http://www.johnath.com/beep/
But simply doesn't beep.

(If I run `$ speaker-test -t sine -f 500 -l 2 2>&1` on the terminal, it beeps, but I would like to beep with c++ to study low-level sound programming)

And I would like to be able to control frequency and duration.

Comment: In order to listen a beep, you need to set up your terminal to allow audible beep (it is disabled by default in many environments). Browse the menu and/or settings dialog of your terminal. Sound programming have nothing to do with the `\a` beep though.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? KDE's Konsole, for example, doesn't support beeping at all. First check that `echo -e \\a` works in your shell. If it doesn't, your C++ code won't work too.

Comment: @Ruslan Dunno about yours but *my* KDE's Konsole does, I just tested it. Of course it just plays a sound file through whatever sound system KDE uses this week, but you can choose one that sounds like a beep.

Comment: @n.m. maybe they've implemented it after KDE 4.14. I'm using KDE4 currently, can't check with KF5. I remember there was a bug report about inability to use buzzer at least.

Comment: @Ruslan I'm using 5 but I'm pretty sure the "configure notifications" menu was there since the early days.

Comment: "I would like to be able to control frequency and duration" --- that's obviously not available with `\a`. The beep command should be able to do it if you run it from a linux terminal (not an emulator) as root.

Comment: @n.m. OK, it does appear to support "Play a sound" on _Bell in (Non-)Visible Session_. It's just not enabled by default. But there's no sane way to do it with buzzer. I've made a workaround for this by "Run command" to run `beep -l 100`, but this is too slow to work correctly: repeated pressing <C-h> in bash leads to about 2 beeps/s while my keyboard autorepeat rate is 50 keys/s.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're logged in from the console, `cout` will not refer to the system console. You need to open `/dev/console` and send the `\a` there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int s = open ("/dev/console", O_WRONLY);
    if (s < 0)
        perror ("unable to open console");
    else
    {
        if (write (s, "\a", 1) != 1)
            perror ("unable to beep");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened? Did you get an error? Perhaps your motherboard doesn't have a speaker connected and so cannot beep.

Comment: @BrunoCorrêaZimmermann Then it's likely your case has no speaker or your motherboard's speaker connector is unconnected. You'll have to command the sound card to make a beeping sound.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on terminal emulator are you using. KDE's Konsole, for example, doesn't support beeping with buzzer at all AFAICT. First check that `echo -e \\a` works in your shell. If it doesn't, your C++ code won't work too. You can use `xterm` — it does support this.

But even in `xterm` it may not work if you don't have `pcspkr` (or `snd_pcsp`) kernel module loaded. This is often the case when distros blacklist it by default. In this case your bet is looking for a terminal which uses your sound card to emit beeps, not PC speaker AKA buzzer.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about "low level sound generation", typically, the lowest level of sound generation would involve constructing a wave form and passing it to the audio device in an appropriate format. Of course, then it comes out from your sound card rather than the PC speaker. The best advice I can give would be to read up on the APIs associated with pulse audio, alsa, or even the kernel sound drivers. Last time I played with this (~1996), it basically meant allocating an array of samples, and then computing values to put in there that approximated a sine wave with the appropriate frequency and amplitude, then writing that buffer to the output device. There may have even been some calls to `ioctl` to set the parameters on the device (sample rate, stereo vs. mono, bit rate, etc). If your audio device supports midi commands, it may be easier to send those in some form that is closer to "play these notes for this long using this instrument".

You may find these articles helpful:

- https://jan.newmarch.name/LinuxSound/
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried system call in your application?

system("echo -e '\a'");